# How to create a new window on the bottom starting from this configuration

Tags: window-splitting

Starting from this window configuration of 5 windows split like this

[image]

How do I create a sixth window that would take all the bottom space like the outline in red?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`split-root-window-below` with a size argument almost does this, only that it scales the existing windows differently than you want.

This function gives the exact behavior in the picture:

```
(defun my-split-root-window-below ()
  (interactive)
  (split-root-window-below (/ (frame-height) -4))
  (window-resize
   (window-in-direction 'above)
   (- (/ (frame-height) 2)
      (/ (- (frame-height)
            (/ (frame-height) 4))
         2))))
```